# Multi Friend Selector Dialog - Show user lists

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to show the custom friend lists that the user has created, in the Multi Friend Selector Dialog? Right now the only options are:

- All Friends
- Application Users
- Friends to Invite
- Selected

Answer (score 0):

Multi Friend Selector Dialog is no longer provided by Facebook. You need to write a custom version.

If you have it working, it'll stop in about 2 weeks. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/

Comment: Can you help me find the same dialog in the Javascript SDK? I have looked around http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ with no luck. Thanks!